# SWIG typedef - Return array to Perl

Tags: c, arrays, perl, int, swig

I have a SWIG file to get output int array from .C file and pass it to Perl so that i can print array value in Perl. There is a Function in C source, which will return an int array. When I'm tried to print those values in Perl, it is not printing Array value.

I have this swig file called perl.i 
This is what I try:

```
#ifdef SWIGPERL
%module aticara
%{
#include "include.h"
extern int myfunction();
%}
%typemap(out) int [ANY] {
}
int myfunction();
#endif
```

I don't know what to write inside typemap. 
The perl script called test.pl, when it runs, but the array is empty:
Here is my test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use aticara;
use feature qw(say);

my $arr = aticara::myfunction();
my $list = $arr;

my $i = 0;
for ( @$list ) {
   say "$i: '$_'";
    $i=$i+1;
}
```

It is printing empty.
I don't no what i am missing and where. But one thing i can tell is that it is from my swig file.
And also i am sharing my C file where it will return an Array list.

Here is my c file:

```
int myfunction()
{
    int a[5];
    a[0] = 45;
    a[1] = 4;
    a[2] = 8;
    a[3] = 9;
    a[4] = 1;
    return *a;
}
```

Expected output in Perl is:

```
0: 45 
1: 4 
2: 8 
3: 9 
4: 1
```

But i can't able to get this output. I don't no that much in swig.
If someone help me to get out, that will be great.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your C function returns `int`, not pointer to an array of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a pointer to an int array and not the content of the first element of the local array `a`. Instead create the array using `malloc()` and make use of the SWIG `ret` typemap to free it up. Then also create an `out` typemap to convert the returned array to a Perl array. Here is an example of how it can be done:

**example.i**

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%typemap(out) int * {
    AV *myav;
    SV **svs;
    int len = 0;
    /* Figure out how many elements we have */
    while ($1[len])
        len++;
    svs = (SV **) malloc(len*sizeof(SV *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len ; i++) 
        svs[i] = newSViv($1[i]);
    myav = av_make(len, svs);
    free(svs);
    $result = newRV_noinc((SV*)myav);
    sv_2mortal($result);
    argvi++;
}
%typemap(ret) int * %{
  free($1);
%}
%include "example.h"
```

**example.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
extern int *myfunction();
```

**example.c**

```
#include "example.h"

int *myfunction()
{
    int *a = (int *) malloc( 5*sizeof(int) );
    a[0] = 45;
    a[1] = 4;
    a[2] = 8;
    a[3] = 9;
    a[4] = 1;
    return a;
}
```

**test.pl**

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use example;

my $arr = example::myfunction();

my $i = 0;
for ( @$arr ) {
    say "$i: '$_'";
    $i++;
}
```

### Compilation (Ubuntu 16.10 with perlbrew):

```
swig -perl5 example.i
perl_dir=~/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/5.24.1/x86_64-linux/CORE 
gcc -fpic -c example.c
gcc -fpic -c -Dbool=char -D_GNU_SOURCE -I"$perl_dir" example_wrap.c
gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.so
```

### Running

```
$ perl test.pl
0: '45'
1: '4'
2: '8'
3: '9'
4: '1'
```

Comment: I changed the code with yours and i tried with Centos 6.8 but it is not working. Here is my compilation as shown below:

    (swig -perl5 -o perl_wrap.c perl.i)         
    (gcc -g -c -fpic  perl_wrap.c  -I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE)
    (gcc -g -fpic   -c perlFunctions.c)
    (gcc -g -shared perl_wrap.o perlFunctions.o   -o aticara.so)

Comment: Hi Adarsha. It is difficult to see exactly what is wrong from your comment. Could you send me the files you used by email, then it will be easier for me to debug?

Comment: Hi Hakon, I have mailed you the codes, please have look.

Comment: Hi Hakon, Thank you for the help, I solved this problem. Now i can able to print array values in Perl script.

Comment: @AdarshaVerma Great to hear, please share the problem that you encountered with my answer and how you solved it, as it might be useful for future readers to know :)

Comment: I just added extern int *myfunction(); in swig interface file. Previously it was defined like this: 
    %module example
    %{
    #include "example.h"
    %}

I changed above code like:
    %module example
    %{
    #include "example.h"
    extern int *myfunction();
    %}
This change worked for me fine : )

Comment: And also i declared extern int *myfunction(); and int myfunction(); i same swig file that was my mistake, I don't want to declare twice, i removed int myfunction(); That's it!!

Comment: Ok :) good! Since this question now seemed to be solved, please accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Actually yo do return a reference to array. Therefore you can't write `($a, $b) = myfunction()`. Is there a way to really return an array?